# In Star Fox Adventures is there any known way to escape Krazoa Palace?

Tags: star-fox-adventures

Now I know that Star Fox Adventures is a relatively older game. I didn't know this would happen and I saved the game after obtaining the 5th Krazoa Spirit. This railroads the game into making you go to Krazoa Palace where you then get pushed down the path to the final boss. Now the game itself won't let you leave in that as far as I can tell the warp out of the palace is blocked behind a grating and the Arwing doesn't let you fly it out of the palace.

I'm guessing that someone somewhere has found a way out of the palace at that portion of the game. Even if it is a glitch method that involves breaking the game to wall clip or something I'm just wanting to know how to get out. I have 12 hours in this play through and now it's gone because the game wasn't reasonable enough to leave a way out of the palace. I'm wondering if anyone has managed to break their way out (even if doing so prevents you from reentering and thereby blocks off the final boss).

Answer (score -3):

Once you've obtained the 5th Krazoa Spirit, you'll be sent to the Krazoa Palace. Make your way down the small wind shaft near Krystal's prison. You'll descend down to the second floor of the palace and find a hallway that leads to a Krazoa Shrine. Release the spirit there, then a cutscene should play revealing a teleporter that will allow you to travel to the location of the final Krazoa Spirit, and by then you should be pretty much locked into place to beat the game. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: They need to get out of a spot to do that. Their problem is that they are stuck

Comment: @Robbie No, I can do that. It just outright fails to address the question outright and the answer should be deleted. **I do not want to complete the game. I want to leave the final boss area and go play in the other over world sections that the game (by design) locks out.**